tcp previous segment not captured

I'm attempting to remotely control a device with c code. I could not send commands. I'm also not able to see the commands entering Wireshark either. Whenever I execute the code, it displays the error depicted in the image. why could it be

First of all, this question is not a good fit for serverfault. Second, you don't show us your code, nor do you explain what your code does, nor what errors you get - you show a wireshark screenshot. I would suggest including the information I mention, and asking it on e.g. StackOverflow.

Oddly, I just had the same problem with Wireshark on Windows an hour earlier; it kept missing a lot of outbound packets for TCP streams.
